# How to create multiple tokens for different client type in ASP .NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, access-token

I am working on an application with Web API and different clients(Mobile app, browser). I want to have different access token for each client type for same user. The reason is, so that the user can sign-out from one device but stays logged in on other devices (similar to how it happens with Facebook).

I know the ASP .Net Identity framework generates single token for a user disregarding the client type. Is there any other framework? Or should it has to be done by storing some client detail in database?

Comment: Reached any conclusions yet?

Comment: I have started the implementation which you suggest. Will update soon. On a side note, for sign-out people say to forgot the token at client side. Is there any secure way than this?

Comment: Forgetting the token at client side is a good practice. Apart from that setting shorter expiry for the token at server will be better.

Comment: Another improvement can be implementing refresh tokens.

Comment: I also realised I need to handle the case when user changes their password. Need to invalidate all other tokens then and force to re-login.

Comment: What did you implement at the end? I am curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the token manually and at that time you can add claims to the token and give them back to the client. Once clients makes request to the server, you can extract the claim from the token and decide on the device type.

Create token like below :

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);

AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, new AuthenticationProperties());
var currentUtc = new SystemClock().UtcNow;
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("device_type", "android/ios/web"));

ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
var expiryInterval = int.Parse("20");

var access_token = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
```

Access token in the request and the claim from token as mentioned below :

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal = Request.GetRequestContext().Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
var customClaimValue = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "device_type").Single().Value;
```

"customClaimValue" must have your device type.

Answer (score 1):

I believe generating different tokens for different clients is unnecessary to achieve you goal. First of, in asp.net a new bearer token is issued for each token request to the /token endpoint.

so, each client is issued a different token for each request. Then the client (web, mobile or any other) can then save the token and use it to access an authorized resource. Logout is only a matter of forgetting the token on the client side.

**NOTE:** Remember to issue tokens with short lived expiration time for security reasons and you can use refresh tokens ends to issue new tokens once expired.

Comment: You must generate a new refreshtoken and accesstoken when user logs in. Therefore, the devices will necessarily have different tokens associated to the user account. What you are saying does not make any sense.